# How to access predefined variables by means of variable variables

Tags: php, post

I was hoping to create a function that will check for `POST` or `GET` data. I wanted to call it like so:

```
hasData("POST");
```

Which would return true or false, depending on whether or not the predefined variable name passed contained data, obviously.

I thought I'd be able to do something like:

```
function hasData($t = 'POST'){
    $varType = "_" . strtoupper($t);
    return !empty( ${$varType} );
}
```

`$_POST` is apparently undefined when I do it like this, but getting the variable like so:

```
${"_POST"}
```

works not a problem.

I resorted to the documentation and [found a comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#81033) relating to this. I was wondering:

- Firstly why I'm not allowed to pass a variable into the curly braces to get a predefined variable's value?
- Secondly, is there a more elegant way of going about this than (as suggested in the comment) declaring the variable globally first?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use $_REQUEST?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason to do this in the first place. Wouldn't `empty( $_POST )` be an easier way of doing exactly what you're doing? Especially since the options are really just $_GET and $_POST since $_REQUEST is a combination of the two.

Comment: @Brian This is part of a bigger picture where I wanted to use my own class to check these variables - the class will have other functionality, I'd rather have `empty()` in one place. You make a good point about `$_REQUEST` -- I didn't think that far ahead I was mainly curious as to why this isn't do-able.

Comment: Ah well that makes a lot more sense then ;) what @Haig Bedrosian answered below is correct and should set you straight.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned in the question - my fault. HaidBed doesn't really answer the second part since `$$varType` still doesn't work. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Although not idea why not just do a case statement and call `$_POST`directly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears $GLOBALS variable also contains $_GET and $_POST variables (wasn't able to find any reference though).

```php
function hasData($t = 'POST'){
    $varType = "_" . strtoupper($t);
    return !empty($GLOBALS[$varType]);
}
```